# Implementing bootstrap pagination on jsf page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsf-2, pagination

I have a list of records which i print on the screen using ui:repeat tag. But sometimes the size of the list of records are too long. You can consider my records as search results in google. I need to implement a paginator (just like in google search) for my ui. So that the user can navigate to different page to see more results. I would prefer to use twitter bootstrap components. My records will look somewhat like these.

```
<ui:repeat var="user" value="#{list.users}">
        <strong>#{user.userName} , #{user.firstName} #{user.lastName} </strong>
        <em>#{user.emailAddress}</em>   
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: E.g. Richfaces brings a dataScroller component to be used with datatable or datagrid. You are using plain JSF without any *Faces on top, aren't you?

Comment: I am using jsf with primefaces , but i dont want to use a dataTable as does not look very nice with the results i am displaying.

Answer (score -1):

A jquery plugin is already available for bootstrap pagination at http://bootstrappaginator.org/